# Global search not returning converted lead

Tags: leads, lead-conversion

We are searching globally with a system administrator profile for a specific email and no results are shown. However, when using the "Mass Delete Lead" feature from the Setup, I can find a converted lead with that specific email.

How can converted lead be searchable for users?

Comment: find my answer, global search could return that based on View and Edit Converted Lead Permission

Answer (score 1):

Once converted, a lead record is no longer searchable in Salesforce Classic. However, the new account, contact, or opportunity record created from the converted lead is searchable. In Lightning Experience, both the converted lead record and the new record based on the converted lead are searchable; however, you can’t access the converted lead record to view or edit from the search results page.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=leads_notes.htm&type=0

Comment: thanks how do I search that in Lightning? I tried but I am unable to

Comment: that is another different question.. :)  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_enable_intro.htm&type=0

Comment: aha I do have lightning experience enabled. but searching that email doesn't return any record. Can I get there through the account?

Comment: So when you search in lightning you should get an autocomplete search box that show the converted lead.  You cannot view or edit the converted lead.. You will get this message.. 
Looks like there's a problem.
This lead was already converted to the contact..

Why are you trying to search for converted leads in 1st place??

Comment: I search by email but no autocomplete appears. My issue is that I need to change the email of that lead to allow that email to be used for another lead

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000170793&type=1

Comment: Thanks how do I find the leadID though?

Comment: @BenjaminPirih converted lead can be searched in Classic, refer my ans

Comment: Not working in Summer17 for us, can't search by email of a converted lead even with permissions

Answer (score 1):

You can view Converted lead from Global search.

For that create a permission set and assign, `View and Edit Converted Leads` permission and then assign the permission sets to the user.

Refer this [Spring 17 Release Notes - View and Edit Converted Leads](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_sales_leads_view_converted.htm)

[image: release notes]

Refer [Let Users View and Edit Converted Leads documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=leads_view_edit_converted.htm&type=0) which will guide you as to how you can provide permission.

Here, it the screenshots from Global Search results

[image: search results]

Comment: In summer17 this is not working for us. If we search by email we do not find anything.